# Magento 1.7: Importing products with multiselect attributes

Tags: magento, csv, import, attributes, product

I have created a working CSV structure to be used with native Magento Import (System/Import/Export/Import).

Here is an example of my structure, with simple products and configurable products based on the first ones.

```
"sku","_store","_attribute_set","_product_websites","_type","name","price","special_price","news_from_date","news_to_date","tax_class_id","short_description","description","meta_description","meta_keyword","meta_title","_root_category","_category","has_options","color","talla","coleccion","composition","prestaciones_tecnicas","tejido_tecnico","_links_upsell_sku","image","small_image","thumbnail","status","visibility","weight","qty","is_in_stock","_media_attribute_id","_media_image","_media_lable","_media_position","_media_is_disabled","_super_products_sku","_super_attribute_code","_super_attribute_option"
"1601127-A-NEGRO/ROJO FUEGO-S",,"CustomAttrs","base","simple","CHALECO NAREM - A-NEGRO/ROJO FUEGO - S","81.95","",,,"0","Blabla blabla","Blabla blabla",,,,"Default Category","MUJER/PRENDA/CHALECO","0","A-NEGRO/ROJO FUEGO","S",,,,,,,,,"1","1","0","1","1",,,,,,,,
"1601127-A-NEGRO/ROJO FUEGO-M",,"CustomAttrs","base","simple","CHALECO NAREM - A-NEGRO/ROJO FUEGO - M","81.95","",,,"0","Blabla blabla","Blabla blabla",,,,"Default Category","MUJER/PRENDA/CHALECO","0","A-NEGRO/ROJO FUEGO","M",,,,,,,,,"1","1","0","2","1",,,,,,,,
"1642238-A-NEGRO/ROJO FUEGO-S",,"CustomAttrs","base","simple","CHAQUETA SERKA - A-NEGRO/ROJO FUEGO - S","97.35","",,,"0","Blabla blabla","Blabla blabla",,,,"Default Category","MUJER/PRENDA/CHAQUETA","0","A-NEGRO/ROJO FUEGO","S",,,,,,,,,"1","1","0","2","1",,,,,,,,
"1642238-A-NEGRO/ROJO FUEGO-M",,"CustomAttrs","base","simple","CHAQUETA SERKA - A-NEGRO/ROJO FUEGO - M","97.35","",,,"0","Blabla blabla","Blabla blabla",,,,"Default Category","MUJER/PRENDA/CHAQUETA","0","A-NEGRO/ROJO FUEGO","M",,,,,,,,,"1","1","0","1","1",,,,,,,,
"1601127",,"CustomAttrs","base","configurable","CHALECO NAREM","81.95","","2013-04-29 00:00:00","2013-05-29 00:00:00","0","Blabla blabla","Blabla blabla","Blabla blabla","CHALECO,CORTAVIENTOS,REPELENCIA AL AGUA","CHALECO NAREM","Default Category","MUJER/PRENDA/CHALECO","1",,,"CITY CYCLING","",,,,"","","","1","4",,,,"88","","","1","0",,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Default Category","MUJER",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Default Category","MUJER/PRENDA",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"ACTIVE SOFTSHELL",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"transpirable",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"stretch",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"costuras flatlock",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"tratamiento anti uv",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Repelente al agua",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"1601127-A-NEGRO/ROJO FUEGO-S","talla","S"
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"1601127-A-NEGRO/ROJO FUEGO-S","color","A-NEGRO/ROJO FUEGO"
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"1601127-A-NEGRO/ROJO FUEGO-M","talla","M"
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"1601127-A-NEGRO/ROJO FUEGO-M","color","A-NEGRO/ROJO FUEGO"
"1642238",,"CustomAttrs","base","configurable","CHAQUETA SERKA","97.35","","2013-04-29 00:00:00","2013-05-29 00:00:00","0","Blabla blabla","Blabla blabla","Blabla blabla","CHAQUETA,CORTAVIENTOS,REPELENCIA AL AGUA","CHAQUETA SERKA","Default Category","MUJER/PRENDA/CHAQUETA","1",,,"CITY CYCLING","",,,,"","","","1","4",,,,"88","","","1","0",,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Default Category","MUJER",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Default Category","MUJER/PRENDA",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"ACTIVE SOFTSHELL",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"transpirable",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"stretch",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"costuras flatlock",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"tratamiento anti uv",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"Repelente al agua",,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"1642238-A-NEGRO/ROJO FUEGO-S","talla","S"
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"1642238-A-NEGRO/ROJO FUEGO-S","color","A-NEGRO/ROJO FUEGO"
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"1642238-A-NEGRO/ROJO FUEGO-M","talla","M"
,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,"1642238-A-NEGRO/ROJO FUEGO-M","color","A-NEGRO/ROJO FUEGO"
```

**The import works good, with no error.** But something strange is happens: I have some custom attributes created. Some of them are atributes of only one value selectable but I have two attributes that have multiselect values, and these two are the problematic ones (prestaciones_tecnicas & tejido_tecnico).

After importing, I reindex, clean cache and everything...and when I go to a detail of a product at frontend, **i see every thing ok except the two multiselect attributes, whose information does not appearing**. I make a Zend_Debug::dump() of those attributes, and are empty. But surprisingly when I edit the product at the admin of Magento, these attributes appears correctly and with the corresponding values selected (the values that I had indicated at the CSV).

The more strange thing is that if simply **I edit one of those products, and save it (without changing anything), then those attributes magically appears OK at frontend!!!** And I don't change anything! Just edit and save!

Any idea? I have a lot of products...and going one by one editing/saving is not a posible solution for me...

Very grateful!

Answer (score 2):

Wondering why still no one mentioned MAGMI as a solution for this issue and a great alternative for native magento dataflow profiles. It's a very powerful tool for any kind of magento imports. You can check all its features in wiki.magmi.org

Configurable products can be created very easily from just a one row of csv file, here's an example:

```
 type           configurable_attributes   super_attribute_pricing
 configurable   size,color                size::L:12;XL:15,color::red:10;green:15
```

And the multiselect attributes can be imported just fine, what is tested by lots of people.
For example:

```
 sku       name      description       price     Size:multiple:1
 T-Shirt1  T-Shirt   A T-Shirt         5.00      Small|Medium|Large
 T-Shirt2  T-Shirt2  Another T-Shirt   6.00      XS|S|M|L|XL
```

In this example 2 products with custom options will be created. Custom option is 'Size' of multi select type and required for selection ('1' at the end).
Each product has it's sizes, Small/Medium/Large for 1st product and XS/S/M/L/XL for the second one.

This is just a quick hint on 2 basic features - impressing, isn't it?

So I'd highly recommend to consider MAGMI as an import tool for magento.

And If you consider paid extensions there is a nice extension [here](http://www.magelynx.com/shop/import-export-plugin.html), it's an ui wrap around MAGMI that also supports exporting product data in magmi format, not only import as plain magmi does. It works with Google spreadsheets instead of CSV and exports data right into the csv columns with headers according to magmi syntax.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the standard Magento import needs all the options of the multiple select attribute in seperate rows. You can see that when exporting a correctly set product.

Unfortunately this greatly reduces the compatibility with other software.

But fortunately indeed there is a plugin for this:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/import-products-categories-multiple-images-and-custom-options.html

Hope this helps. Good luck!

**UPDATE:**

There is a small bug in the extention, maybe only in combination with multi store sites. 
You can still import category_ids (which is not mentioned in the readme) but it crashes when importing category names.
The bug seems to be somewhere in the function _addCategories() in this file:

\app\code\community\CapacityWebSolutions\ImportProduct\Model\Convert\Adapter\Product.php
Maybe something wrong with store id. Thats why it might only occur in multi store sites.

Unfortunately I could not set this function straight so I had to do a workaround.

It won't CREATE categories anymore but reliably import into already set categories. 
I replaced these lines 95-105 of the file mentioned above:

```
    if (isset($importData['category_ids'])) {
        $product->setCategoryIds($importData['category_ids']);
    }
     /*    if category name is in csv file        */
    if (isset($importData['categories'])) {

        $categoryIds = $this->_addCategories($importData['categories'], $store);
        if ($categoryIds) {
            $product->setCategoryIds($categoryIds);
        }
    }
```

With this (replacement filter is country specific of course and maybe the attribute_id in the mysql query should be dynamic...):

```
      // NM5 translate category names in category IDs ///////////////////
    if (isset($importData['categories'])) {

        $nm5_cat_names = preg_split('/,/',$importData['categories']);

        $nm5_read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('core_read');
        $nm5_cat_table = Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix().'catalog_category_entity_varchar';
        $originals = array('\'', '"', '\\', ';', '<', '>', '(', ')', '[', ']', '{', '}', '|', '$', '=', '%', 'Ä', 'Ö', 'Ü', 'ä', 'ö', 'ü', 'ß', ' - ', '  ', ' ', '_', '.', '?', '!', '³', ',', '„', '“', '+', '-–-', '–-' );
        $replacements =    array('', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'Ae', 'Oe', 'Ue', 'ae', 'oe', 'ue', 'ss', '-', '-', '-', '-', '', '', '', '3', '-', '', '', '-plus', '-', '-' );
        $nm5_i = 0;

        while($nm5_cat_names[$nm5_i] != '' ){
            $filtered_text = strtolower(str_replace($originals, $replacements, $nm5_cat_names[$nm5_i]));

            $nm5_results = $nm5_read->fetchAll("SELECT entity_id FROM $nm5_cat_table WHERE value LIKE '$filtered_text' and attribute_id = 51 group by entity_id");

            if($nm5_i > 0){ $categoryIds .= ','; }
            $categoryIds .= $nm5_results[0]['entity_id'];

            $nm5_i++;
        }

        // $categoryIds = $this->_addCategories($importData['categories'], $store);
        if ($categoryIds) {
            $categoryIds;
            $product->setCategoryIds($categoryIds);
        }

    }elseif(isset($importData['category_ids'])){

        $product->setCategoryIds($importData['category_ids']);

    }
    // NM5 translate category names in category IDs ///////////////////
```